# trying to pull a calculation if a radio button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

What i am trying to do now is have separate calculation when a radio button is highlighted for particular fields... in this case if the radio button is highlightedior "yearly" i want the user input of the text field to be calculated maintFees * 1 = x variable and show that output in maintTimesTwelve.

if not highlighted for "yearly" i want it to be calculated by maintFees * 12. and shown in maintTimesTwelve.

js fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ryx4qt0d/

here is the copy of my code

```js
            // start of variables 
                 function yearlyPayment(){
      var monthlyPayment = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
      var maintFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintFees").value);
      var memFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("memFees").value);
      var exchFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("exchFees").value);
      var result = (monthlyPayment?monthlyPayment:0) + (maintFees?maintFees:0) + (memFees?memFees:0) + (exchFees?exchFees:0);
        
      document.getElementById("txtResult").value = result;}
          
            //first function after submission
    function mpTwelve(){
        
      var monPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
      var monTwe = monPay * 12;

      document.getElementById("mpTimesTwelve").value = monTwe;}
            // sencond function
    function maintTwelve(){
        
      var maintPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintFees").value);
      var maintTwe = maintPay * 12;
      var x = maintPay * 1;
        
        if (document.getElementByClass("year").checked){
            
            document.getElementById("mantTimesTwelve").value = x;
        } 
        else{

            document.getElementById("maintTimesTwelve").value = maintTwe;}
    }
            // third function
    function yearlyTen(){
        var yearPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtResult").value);
        var yearTen = yearPay * 120;
        
        document.getElementById("totalYearly").value = yearTen;}
            
            //4th function
    function yearlyTenMaint(){
        var tenMain = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintTimesTwelve").value);
        var tenMainTen = (tenMain * 120) * .5;
        
        document.getElementById("maintTenYear").value = tenMainTen;}
            
            //fifth function
    function totalMeEx(){
        var meEx = parseInt(document.getElementById("memFees").value);
        var exMe = parseInt(document.getElementById("exchFees").value);
        var totalExMe = (meEx + exMe) * 120;
        
        document.getElementById("totalMemDues").value = totalExMe;
    }
```

```html
    <div>

    <p>
        Monthly payment:<br>
    <input type="text" id="monthlyPayment" class="input"/><br>
    Maintenance fees:<br>
    <input style="margin-left: 79px" type="text" id="maintFees"     class="input"/>
        <input type="radio" id="year" name="year" class="year">
            <label for="year"> Yearly </label><br>
        
    Membership dues:<br><br>
    <input type="text" id="memFees" class="input"/><br>
    xchange Fees<br>
    <input type="text" id="exchFees" class="input"/><br>

    <br>
     Annual timeshare vacation cost:<br>
      <input type="text" id="txtResult"/><br>
      Monthly payment x 12<br>
      <input type="text" id="mpTimesTwelve"/><br>
      Maintenance fees x 12<br>
      <input type="text" id="maintTimesTwelve"/><br>
      Total yearly payment x10 years:<br>
      <input type="text" id="totalYearly"/><br>
      Yearly Mainteneance over 10 years w/ 5% increase:<br>
      <input type="text" id="maintTenYear"/><br>
      Membership Dues + Exchange Fees x 10 years:<br>
      <input type="text" id="totalMemDues"/><br>
            
    <button onclick="yearlyPayment(); mpTwelve(); maintTwelve();yearlyTen(); yearlyTenMaint();totalMeEx();">calculate</button><br>
    </p></div>
```

Comment: ok.  and what doesn't work?

Comment: when i click the radio button nothing changes.. and everything after the function mpTwelve does not work.

Comment: Check the console to find this error: `TypeError: document.getElementByClass is not a function` it should be `getElementByClassName`

Comment: nice catch. yup just changed it and it doesn't calculate. it will calculate if i do not presser's yearly, but won't if i do.

Answer (score 0):

`if (document.getElementByClass("year").checked){` should be `if (document.getElementsByClassName("year")[0].checked){` because *getElementsByClassName()* returns a collection. Can be simplified by using `if (document.querySelector(".year").checked){`

You had a typo here: `document.getElementById("mantTimesTwelve")` *mant* should be *maint*

**Please:** Check the console everytime a script doesn't run, it's so easy to find this kind of errors.

```js
// start of variables 
                 function yearlyPayment(){
      var monthlyPayment = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
      var maintFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintFees").value);
      var memFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("memFees").value);
      var exchFees = parseInt(document.getElementById("exchFees").value);
      var result = (monthlyPayment?monthlyPayment:0) + (maintFees?maintFees:0) + (memFees?memFees:0) + (exchFees?exchFees:0);
        
      document.getElementById("txtResult").value = result;}
          
            //first function after submission
    function mpTwelve(){
        
      var monPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPayment").value);
      var monTwe = monPay * 12;

      document.getElementById("mpTimesTwelve").value = monTwe;}
            // sencond function
    function maintTwelve(){
        
      var maintPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintFees").value);
      var maintTwe = maintPay * 12;
      var x = maintPay * 1;
        
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("year")[0].checked){
            
            document.getElementById("maintTimesTwelve").value = x;
        } 
        else{

            document.getElementById("maintTimesTwelve").value = maintTwe;
        }
    }
            // third function
    function yearlyTen(){
        var yearPay = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtResult").value);
        var yearTen = yearPay * 120;
        
        document.getElementById("totalYearly").value = yearTen;}
            
            //4th function
    function yearlyTenMaint(){
        var tenMain = parseInt(document.getElementById("maintTimesTwelve").value);
        var tenMainTen = (tenMain * 120) * .5;
        
        document.getElementById("maintTenYear").value = tenMainTen;}
            
            //fifth function
    function totalMeEx(){
        var meEx = parseInt(document.getElementById("memFees").value);
        var exMe = parseInt(document.getElementById("exchFees").value);
        var totalExMe = (meEx + exMe) * 120;
        
        document.getElementById("totalMemDues").value = totalExMe;
    }
```

```html
<div>

    <p>
        Monthly payment:<br>
    <input type="text" id="monthlyPayment" class="input"/><br>
    Maintenance fees:<br>
    <input style="margin-left: 79px" type="text" id="maintFees"     class="input"/>
        <input type="radio" id="year" name="year" class="year">
            <label for="year"> Yearly </label><br>
        
    Membership dues:<br><br>
    <input type="text" id="memFees" class="input"/><br>
    xchange Fees<br>
    <input type="text" id="exchFees" class="input"/><br>

    <br>
     Annual timeshare vacation cost:<br>
      <input type="text" id="txtResult"/><br>
      Monthly payment x 12<br>
      <input type="text" id="mpTimesTwelve"/><br>
      Maintenance fees x 12<br>
      <input type="text" id="maintTimesTwelve"/><br>
      Total yearly payment x10 years:<br>
      <input type="text" id="totalYearly"/><br>
      Yearly Mainteneance over 10 years w/ 5% increase:<br>
      <input type="text" id="maintTenYear"/><br>
      Membership Dues + Exchange Fees x 10 years:<br>
      <input type="text" id="totalMemDues"/><br>
            
    <button onclick="yearlyPayment(); mpTwelve(); maintTwelve();yearlyTen(); yearlyTenMaint();totalMeEx();">calculate</button><br>
    </p></div>
```